# upload and download to Ftpserver in a asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am designing a website and in one of my website page I want to access to a local Ftp server and upload and download files from it but I dont know how to design it like a list and how to download and upload and delet Files From Ftp would u plz guide me?

Comment: Are you providing users FTP access to some files on the web server? If yes, then, for you, the files are local and you should be able to use the Directory class to get the list of files/directories (no need to use FtpWebRequest). If the files are located on another machine that only allows FTP access to them, then you will want to use FtpWebRequest (see the answer from @Xeano).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class to do this. I think you should try to get a list of files before you do any uploading/downloading, as a read is usually the easiest to do.

You can see how to get a directory list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx).

Also, do not think of this as a asp.net "thing". It's part of the .Net framework. Create a service (or dal/repo) - a class which is responsible for handling your ftp calls. This way you can decouple it from the rest of your code.

You can then use a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z5184w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to show the contents of your ftp.

Comment: But I want to show the directory list geraphical with buttons downlaod and upload and delete and really get confused after alot of searching

Comment: Retrieving the data is the first step, you need the data before you can display anything. For displaying ftp data, a TreeView is perfect. This is also built into asp.net.

Comment: Please follow this guide in order to retrieve the list of data, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx - It's a really good one. Once you have the data you can start working on an asp.net representation of the data.

Comment: @ Xeano but this is not what I want this is a c# code and console app.and I want a graphical interface and download and upload and really dont know how to create it